# Multiple CSS-files doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've created a really simple page with bootstrap. (I have one bootstrap component)
I've added an extra css file but it doesnt work while bootstrap.min.css is included.

Anybody knows why?

my page:

```
<html>
<head>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css" type="text/css"> <-- This won't work
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"> <-- while this is included
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <TITLE>TestDev</TITLE>
</head>
<body>

<div class="well">
<p>Welcome</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

mystyle.css

```
body{
    background-color: darkred;
}
.well{
    background: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order of the styles included. `mystyle.css` should be included after Twitter Bootstrap file in order to overwrite the default style.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mystyle.css" type="text/css">
```